# How to create a thread in C program

Tags: c, winapi

I am tryin to create a thread using CreateThread() function and execute simple addition function in that thread. I wrote some code . But the thread is not being initiated any way.

Can you please help me in correcting the code

I have gone through MSDN for createthread function

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(LPVOID lpParam){
     int a=1;
     int b=2; 
     int c;
     c = a+b;
     printf("%d",c);
     return 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    DWORD myThreadId;
    HANDLE THread_handle;
    printf("\n I am here inmain");
    THread_handle = CreateThread(NULL,0, ThreadFunc, NULL,0,&myThreadId);
    if (THread_handle == NULL) 
    {
        printf(TEXT("CreateThread"));
        //ExitProcess(3)
     }
    printf("I close\n");
    CloseHandle(THread_handle);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: please format your code, thanks

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread): *A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the _beginthreadex and _endthreadex functions for thread management rather than CreateThread and ExitThread;* I'd start with changing to that. And then look into joining a thread when it ends.

Comment: When `main` returns, your program terminates.

Comment: Please note that printf isn't necessarily thread safe, and both main() and the thread end up calling it simultaneously. Before calling a library function from a thread, you need to establish if it is thread-safe or not.

Comment: @Lundin - Visual C++ runtime is thread safe.  As for overlapping `printf` statements - that might be a different matter with regards to what shows up on the screen.

Comment: In addition to all the other comments: Try to add `Sleep(1000);` right before `return 0;`, maybe the process terminates before the thread has a chance to run.

Comment: @selbie Nobody mentioned neither Visual Studio nor C++.

Comment: @Shawn Actually read what it says. The bug you refer to is some very old crap in the MSVC CRT which was fixed some 15-20 years ago. It does not apply to other compilers. In addition, where exactly does the thread in the question call the CRT?

Comment: @Lundin - fair enough, but he's clearly doing Windows programming. I don't know of a single compiler for Windows without a thread safe runtime.

Comment: @selbie Early Windows compilers were very unsafe in this regard. Modern Windows compilers should hopefully be thread safe. Regardless, there is very little reason to use stdio.h in a Windows program.

Comment: @Lundin Bug? I don't mention any bugs (Or specific compilers); I'm just quoting what the docs say you should be doing. And `printf()` is a CRT function.

Comment: @Shawn It's a very old bug in MSVC - specifically, a bug in MFC. I guess they haven't updated MSDN in 20 years. And MSDN assumes that you are using VC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is likely exiting before the thread you created in main has a chance to finish. Hence, the thread never had a chance to finish and print the result.

Prior to the `CloseHandle` call, add a `WaitForSingleObject` call. This will force the code in main to wait for the thread to complete.

```
    printf("I wait\n");
    WaitForSingleObject(THread_handle, INFINITE);

    printf("I close\n");
    CloseHandle(THread_handle);


    return 0; 
}
```

Further, make sure you flush the output in your thread as well.  `printf` needs an end-of-line char.

Instead of this in `ThreadFunc` :

```
printf("%d",c);
```

Change it to this:

```
printf("%d\n",c);
```

Comment: @KALYAN The key with threading is never to close them, but let them gracefully close by themselves. In Win API programming this is usually done by having the thread repeatedly poll a Windows event with `WaitForSingleObject`. Upon shut-down, the caller will set the event, then wait for the thread to finish.

Comment: There's an API called TerminateThread which is probably what you are getting it.  However, that's a terrible, terrible practice to kill a thread because it will leak memory and other resources.  Possibly OK on shutdown.  But the best practice is to have a way in which your program signals the worker thread to shutdown gracefully before the main program exits - Exactly what Lundin said.